# Select attributes from #create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm creating an object:

```
artist = Artist.create(:name => "Jbeebs",
                       :genre => "bestmusicever", 
                       :plays => "toomany")
```

I would like the variable `artist` to only have the `name` and `genre` attributes so I can return `artist.name` and `artist.genre`, but nothing else.

Is there something like select for creates?

I have an array of artists and would like to return only name and genre of each when I'm outputting JSON.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? With context *(knowing exactly what you're trying to do with `artist`)* you'll likely get better help.

Comment: The short answer: no. The real question: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Updated. I'm creating an array of artists that I'm outputting in JSON and I would like to return only name and genre of each artist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by overloading the `to_json` method in `Artist`

```
def to_json(options = {})
  { name: name, genre: genre }.to_json(options)
end
```

When you cast the method to JSON, it will appear as a JSON object without `:plays` included.

Answer (score 0):

When you output the json, just parse through your artists and create a new object to convert to json:

```
json_array = []
artists.collect{|artist| json_array << {name: artist.name, genre: artist.genre}}
json_array.to_json
```

Otherwise if you always want artists output in json with just those two attributes, use Deefour's answer.